# Why pkexec does't change user in terminal?

Tags: sudo, root, desktop-shortcuts, pkexec

I am trying to run desktop shortcut as root user, willing to see password prompt on opening shortcut.

pkexec does the thing, but it doesn't change user - either i run it from terminal - it always give me a prompt for the current user who is not sudo.

```
pkexec --user root [command]
```

results in

```
Authentication is needed to run [command] as the superuser, 
Authenticating as: mylocal-not-sudo-user
```

How can i change user to root?
(i tried gksudo, but it doesn't pop up prompt on chortcut opening)

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is just to change user to the root, and your system is not administered by a company's policies - the easiest way is to use `sudo` like this `sudo -i`. In this case, the `sudo` will ask your own local password and switch to a shell with root privileges.

To open a terminal from desktop shortcut as root, you have to run the terminal as root: `sudo xterm` or `sudo gnome-terminal`.

The usage of `pkexec` is not a direct equivalent of `sudo`. It does virtually the same, but follows a slightly different set of rules. Which are more flexible (and rigid at the same time) in comparison with a simple group-user policy historically used by `sudo`. You can read on `pkexec` peculiarities by `man 8 polkit`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! My current user Is not sudoers, and I don’t want to give him sudo rights, so I exactly need to execute as root